# A linear functional on the periodic sequences in $\ell^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

> Prove that there exists a continuous nonzero linear fucntional on $\ell^\infty$ that vanishes on every periodic sequence $ x \in \ell^\infty$. (A sequence is periodic if the exists an $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $ n \in \mathbb N$ we have $x_n = x_{n+N}$.)

**Attempt:**

The set $X$ of periodic sequences forms a subspace of $\ell^\infty$. Futher more this subspace has countable (Hamel) basis $\{e_j\}_{j \in \mathbb N}$. Since $\ell^\infty$ is Banach $X$ is meager in $\ell^\infty$ and thus proper. Then there exists a nonperiodic $y \in \ell^\infty \backslash X$ such that $Y := X \oplus \mathbb Cy$ is also proper. Now define on $Y$ the linear functional $f:Y \to \mathbb C$, that such that, (for all $j \in \mathbb N$,) $f(e_j) = 0$ and $f(y) = 1$. By Hahn-Banach Theorem this extends to a linear functional on $\ell^\infty$.

**Questions:**

- Is there a mistake in the above proof
- Is there an explicit construct of such functional
- How to prove it otherwise

Comment: $f$ must be continuous so $y$ non-periodic is not enough, it must also not be a limit of periodic sequences. For the explicit construct, no idea if it is true but I heard that without the axiom of choice we can't prove that $(\ell^\infty)^*$ is larger than $\ell^1$.

Comment: I'm thinking about, how $y$ can be a limit of periodic $x_n$ while not being periodic

Comment: An infinite series of periodic sequences will often not be periodic. For example $y(n)=\sum_{d\ge 1, d | n} d^{-2}$.

Comment: Imagine you start with a wave with period $1$, then you add a wave with period $2$, the resulting wave has period $2$. Then we can keep adding waves with longer and longer periods and the resulting wave will no longer be periodic (it would have "infinite" period).

Comment: I meant sequence, instead of wave...

Answer (score 2):

Let $AP$ denote the norm-closure of the linear span of all periodic sequences in $\ell^\infty$. Define the linear functional $f:AP\to\mathbb{C}$ by $$f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n x_k\hspace{10mm} \forall x=(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \in AP$$ There exist $y\in\ell^\infty$ for which the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n y_k$ does not exist. Consequently, $y\notin AP$ so $AP\neq\ell^\infty$.

Second, by Hahn-Banach theorem, there exists $g\in(\ell^\infty)^*$ such that $g(AP)=\{0\}$ and $g(y) = 1$.

Comment: If I may ask again, though it has been a long time since I asked this question, how can a bounded sequence $(x_n) = x \in \ell^\infty$ not have an average $f(x)$ as you defined it ?

Comment: Perhaps the sequence: $0$, $10$ times $1$, $100$ times $0$, $1000$ times $1$, $10000$ times $0$, $100000$ times $1$, and so on ?

Comment: @Physor if I understood right, your sequence is not bounded. Consider this: let $x_n=1$ if the first digit (in base 10) of $n$ is $1$, and $x_n=0$ otherwise. $(x_n)$ does not have an average.

Comment: No you didn't understand it right. Let me be explicit: I mean the sequence: $(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,....$ 100 zeros$ ...,0,1,1,1,...$ 1000 ones $...,1,0,...$ 10000 zeros $...0,1,...$ 100000 ones $ 1,0, ....)$. This is clearly bounded and it has no average, as the sequence of the average can be shown to not be Cauchy

Comment: @Physor oh yes, that works..

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be the space of periodic sequences. Let $e_1$ be the sequence $(1,0,...)$. Note that for $x \in P$, we have $\|x-e_1\|_\infty \ge \max(|x_1-1|, |x_k|)$ for all $k>1$, and since $x$
is periodic, there is some $k>1$ such that $x_1 = x_k$ and so we have $\|x-e_1\|_\infty \ge {1 \over 2}$.

Hence we can strictly separate $\overline{P}$ and $\{e_1\}$ with some functional $\phi$ such that
$\phi(x) < \phi(e_1)$ for all $x \in P$. Since $P$ is a linear subspace, we must have $\phi(x) = 0$ for all $x \in P$ and hence $\phi(e_1) >0$.

Comment: +1. Nice answer!

Comment: I don't understand why "Since $P$ is a linear subspace, then we must have $\phi(x) = 0$ for all $x \in P$." By what theorem is that

Comment: If there is a non zero value then multiplying by any scalar will allow any value to be reached. Since the range has an upper bound this cannot be true.

Comment: Another point is that $\phi$ should be complex valued, how do you order $\phi(x) < \phi(e_1)$ ? or I misunderstood sth. Sorry for these questions but I'm still beginner in functional analysis

Comment: Are you familiar with the complex version of the geometric form of the Hahn Banach theorem?

Comment: No, I don't know what geometric version ist that. I know that a real-linear functional (on a comlpex space) determines uniquely a complex-linear one, of which it is the real part. Is that what you mean ? I've never read that under the name geometric

Comment: Yes, as opposed to the sublinear dominating version.